# Jquery Cycle plugin - Great problem with Ajax images loading

Tags: ajax, plugins, load, cycle

I've got a problem with the Jquery Cycle pluging.

I load dinamically via Ajax the images of the gallery.

When I click the buttons next or prev of the gallery, the sequence doesn't work correctly.

Sometimes the class activeSlide doesn't change element or an element of the gallery is missed.

If i refresh the page it work correctly.

When i make the ajax call and I change the images inside the gallery I destroy the plugin before and after I redeclare it.

IF I set timeout for the autosliding allworks correctly.

I post the code.

Someone can help me? It's 3 days I try to find a solution :(((((((

Thank you Davide.

This is my code:

```
success: function(data){

    $('#imgcaption').cycle('destroy');//Before load data I destroy the gallery

    $('#dettaglio #imgcaption').empty();//I clean the div's
    $('#dettaglio #nav').empty();

            //I insert the new Images
            $.each(data.foto, function(index, value){
            $('#imgcaption').append('<div><img src="' + value + '" alt="" /></div>');           
    });

            //I redeclare the Cycle 
    $('#imgcaption').cycle({
        timeout: 0,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        speed: 500,
        pager: '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '<a href="#"></a>'; 
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. Apparently jQuery Cycle still sees the old DOM elements after an ajax load. So when you go to apply the .cycle() to the fresh AJAX DOM comes in, jQuery Cycle binds it to both the new DOM from AJAX and the old DOM that was "removed".

That's why your pagination is all screwed up (more specifically, the fist set of page links refer to the old DOM and the later set refer to the fresh AJAX DOM).

So, a fix is to manually remove the DOM elements associated with the cycle after you do your .cycle('destroy')

```
$(".cycleSelector").remove();
$(".pagerSelector").remove();
```

Or in your case:

```
$("#imgcaption").remove();
$("#nav").remove();
```

I hope that helps! There are lot of posts online about this issue with no proposed solutions. Now we have one. :)